# How can I remove grout from closely-spaced tiles?

Tags: grout

Standard tiled shower walls, probably 1/16" or less between tiles.  Needs to be re-grouted.  I've seen the standard "grout saw" like this:

[image]

And this triangle type:

[image]

I can't imagine that removing all the grout with such a beast would be time-consuming and probably give me elbow and/or wrist problems.  Never mind that IME these saws are usually not very narrow and probably wouldn't get all the grout.  Is there a better—preferably mechanized—solution?  This can't be an uncommon issue for us DIYers.

Edit: pic of actual tile:

[image]

Comment: Dremel makes grout removal tools but I haven't seen them smaller than 1/16

Comment: I have seen professionals do this with a Dremel-style tool and small wheel.  I do not know what exactly kind of wheel they used but the tiles and spacing were very similar to yours and they did it in a few hours without damaging any tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Given that grout is generally fairly soft, I'd have a look at thin metal cutting discs in an angle grinder. In the UK, these are typically 1mm thick.

[image]

Bear in mind though, that they are brittle, and will shatter if the disc is not kept straight. It will also generate a *lot* of dust. Make sure good eye/face/breathing protection is used.

Disclaimer: I have no idea how well these discs will actually remove grout, but it's what I would try - mainly because I have some already.

Answer (score 0):

Removing grout with an angle grinder may damage tiles.

If I really can't afford to replace them now, then I'd try to seal them somehow, as a temporary measure.

Or do it right from the start and replace the tiles with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, and safest, hands down is razor blades. It's a non sanded grout on ceramic tile, if you use any power tools and cutting wheels/disks chances are a tile will chip or wheel will jump and then you got added work, a razor blade held at an angle towards the tile will pull that grout out quick. Change the blade very often to keep like brand new sharp, fir a 30 sq ft area you'll probably run through 7 or 8 blades both sides.

Comment: A razor blade to cut out grout?

Comment: Absolutely, I do it all the time, sure I'll go through alot of blades but it beats having to pull tile and replace them because of a chip.